# Change color instead of background color of text in etherpad

Tags: etherpad

I am trying to find solution for "**Authorship color**" in etherpad. People who never used etherpad, please ignore this question as they will not understand.

So normally "Authorship Color" is the color provided as a background-color of the text and it can be given as parameter when initializing the pad. It helps recognizing who has written what in pad.

I want to have white background for all text and change the **text-color** instead of background color depending upon the user. So its like if I provided red color when initializing the pad, I want to have red writing in pad instead of red background and white writing in pad(as usual).

Please dont put this question on hold as I dont have any specific code to provide related to this problem. Ask in comment instead, i will clear whatever is not understandable.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, Thanks to everyone for not blocking or making this question on Post as no piece of code was provided.

I was about to put bounty on this question when I decided to try myself one more time and well I have resolved the problem after going through a lot. Though, it helped me understand etherpad better.

I want to list two important links related to etherpad:

1. https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite/wiki
2. About src - https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite/wiki/Introduction-to-the-source

They can be very important if you are trying to understand etherpad or want to do some modification yourself.

So here is how you do it:

In `src/static/js/ace2_inner.js` , go to `setAuthorStyle` function and Replace:

```
        // author color
        authorStyle.backgroundColor = bgcolor;
        parentAuthorStyle.backgroundColor = bgcolor;

        // text contrast
        if(colorutils.luminosity(colorutils.css2triple(bgcolor)) < 0.5)
        {
          authorStyle.color = '#ffffff';
          parentAuthorStyle.color = '#ffffff';
        }else{
          authorStyle.color = null;
          parentAuthorStyle.color = null;
        }

        // anchor text contrast
        if(colorutils.luminosity(colorutils.css2triple(bgcolor)) < 0.55)
        {
          anchorStyle.color = colorutils.triple2css(colorutils.complementary(colorutils.css2triple(bgcolor)));
        }else{
          anchorStyle.color = null;
        }
```

With:

```
authorStyle.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';
parentAuthorStyle.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';

authorStyle.color = bgcolor;
parentAuthorStyle.color = bgcolor;
```

And comment Out:

```
if ((typeof info.fade) == "number")
{
  bgcolor = fadeColor(bgcolor, info.fade);
}
```

Ofcource dont forget to restart process by `bin/run.sh` for changes to take place.

People, who are interested to understand how it works can keep reading.

So etherpad receives parameters with which etherpad has been initialized in `src/static/js/pad.js` so if you have defined: 'userColor' when you have initialized the pad, it will go in `globalUserColor` in mentioned file.

Then this variable `globalUserColor` populates `pad.myUserInfo.colorId` in same file.

Now in `collab_client.js` , this `colorId` gets stored in `cssColor` in function `tellAceAuthorInfo` and `editor.setAuthorInfo` is being called by giving parameter `bgcolor: cssColor`.

Now this function `setAuthorInfo` exists in `src/static/js/ace2_inner.js` which calls to other native function(same file) `setAuthorStyle` where we have made changes.

What I did is that instead of changing background color with provided variable `bgcolor` which actually holds `userColor` :

```
authorStyle.backgroundColor = bgcolor;
parentAuthorStyle.backgroundColor = bgcolor;
```

I changed `backgroundColor` to white(#ffffff) and color of text to `bgcolor` :

```
authorStyle.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';
 parentAuthorStyle.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';

 authorStyle.color = bgcolor;
 parentAuthorStyle.color = bgcolor;
```

I also deleted:

```
         // text contrast
         if(colorutils.luminosity(colorutils.css2triple(bgcolor)) < 0.5)
         {
           authorStyle.color = '#ffffff';
           parentAuthorStyle.color = '#ffffff';
         }else{
           authorStyle.color = null;
           parentAuthorStyle.color = null;
         }

        // anchor text contrast
         if(colorutils.luminosity(colorutils.css2triple(bgcolor)) < 0.55)
         {
           anchorStyle.color = colorutils.triple2css(colorutils.complementary(colorutils.css2triple(bgcolor)));
         }else{
           anchorStyle.color = null;
         }
```

Because, these lines set the contrast of text color depending upon the background chosen color. But I have made background white and set text color to given `userColor` so I don't need the contrast functionality anymore.

Ultimately I also commented:

```
    if ((typeof info.fade) == "number")
    {
      bgcolor = fadeColor(bgcolor, info.fade);
    }
```

Because it makes the text fade when user is not online, at least for me it did.

So that's it. *I hope it will help* someone who wants same functionality as I did.